# Swift EXC_BAD_ACCESS with default implementation defined in protocol extension

Tags: swift, crash, swift4

The following playground code causes a crash (EXC_BAD_ACCESS) on line 2 when called from 1 (Xcode 9.2, Swift 4). In my mind this is totally valid code.

The crash disappears when the Observable extension is removed and the addObserver method is defined in the implementing class instead (TestObservableImpl).

The crash also disappears if the protocol TestObservableListener is removed and instead TestObserverImpl is used as type constraint on Observer in protocol TestObservable.

Does anyone has a clue why, or is this just a Swift bug?

```
public protocol Observable: class {
    associatedtype Observer: AnyObject
    var observers: [Observer] { get set }
    func addObserver(_ observer: Observer) -> Void
}

public extension Observable {
    public func addObserver(_ observer: Observer) -> Void {
        observers.append(observer)
    }
}

protocol TestObservableListener: class {
    func bla()
}

protocol TestObservable: Observable where Observer == TestObservableListener {
}

class TestObservableImpl: TestObservable {
    typealias Observer = TestObservableListener
    public var observers = [Observer]()
    func broadcast() {
        for observer in observers {
            //2
            observer.bla()
        }
    }
}

class TestObserverImpl: TestObservableListener {
    func bla() {
        print("bla")
    }
}

let observable = TestObservableImpl()
let observer = TestObserverImpl()
observable.addObserver(observer)
//1
observable.broadcast()
```

Comment: Had a quick look and this will also fix the issue: `(observer as! TestObserverImpl).bla()` so it looks like the poor old runtime is having difficulty determining the actual type of the observer object.

Comment: You're right it does fix the crash, however in a real-world scenario the concrete type is not available to the TestObservableImpl (needs to work on protocols).

Comment: I realise it's probably not a solution which is why I added it as a comment not an answer I just thought it might point towards a cause as I hadn't had time to investigate further.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to removing `AnyObject` after `associatedtype Observer` like this:

```
public protocol Observable: class {
  associatedtype Observer
  var observers: [Observer] { get set }
  func addObserver(_ observer: Observer) -> Void
}
```

I tested and it's work.

I think your condition `Observer == TestObservableListener` will compare between `AnyObject` and `Protocol` cause make that error.

Comment: That's nice but for my implementation Observer has to be constrained to AnyObject because it needs to have the reference equality operator defined (===)

Comment: @WernerAltewischer I'm dont fully understand your answer. `observer` is type of `TestObservableListener`. you can compare it: `for observer in observers {
      print(observer === observer) }`

Comment: The real implementation only concerns the Observable protocol, the rest of the sample is just there to clarify my point. In general the associated observer needs to be an object, since it needs to be weakly referencable (in the sample observers is just an array, but in fact it is a sequence implementation which weakly references its objects)

Comment: I will give you an up vote anyway since it is a useful suggestion

Comment: @WernerAltewischer I try to understand exactly what you want. Your protocol conform class `protocol TestObservableListener: class`, I think it means any `Observer` which match `Observer == TestObservableListener` will be an object, right?